# Starting a new Intent from an adapterview is so slow?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-adapterview

I have a ListView which contains different items, each items contains a comment button, so the user will go to another activity where he will be able to comment and see all the comments, but when i click on on the comment's button, it takes time, around 5 seconds, which is very long and different from the other buttons on the same activity.

here is my code from the adapter view :

```
       comment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getContext(), Nouveaucommentaire.class);
                intent.putExtra("objectid", m.getObjectid());
                getContext().startActivity(intent);





        }
 });
```

There is so much load on it

Comment: What does the onCreate/onResume of the comment activity look like? Are you loading stuff?

Comment: I will edit the post and poste the code

Comment: Use Traceview to determine where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not use getContext again and again.
2. Create a context variable in class and initialize in constructor with getContext(); or pass from activity.
3. Use Intent like this.

   Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Nouveaucommentaire.class);
   intent.putExtra("objectid", m.getObjectid());

startActivity(intent);

4. Please manage your code as you can, because some times we do some code in wrong way that effect on app performance, so please aware this things. It will effect on you and your codding.

I hope it will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use Fragments, instead of Activity. And when you are clicking at element, you can just show fragment with element content using FragmentTransaction. As example:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
          .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,android.R.animator.fade_out)
          .show(detailFragment)
          .commit();
```